# JQuery Pass COLOR of default row to next row when hyperlink is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

hey guys its a zebra strip table for jquery im wondering how can i make the hyperlink onclick pass the color of certain row to the bottom or top? 
"Clicking the DN link must cause the highlighted row class .highlight to move up to the previous row.  Loop the effect of the UP and DN buttons around the table so it doesn't stall when you reach the top or bottom of the table.  "

my code

```js
$(function(){
     $(".odd").hover(function() {
     $(this).toggleClass("hovered");
     }, function() {
     $(this).toggleClass("hovered");
     });
    });
    
    
    $(function(){
     $(".even").hover(function() {
     $(this).toggleClass("hovered");
     }, function() {
     $(this).toggleClass("hovered");
     });
    });
```

```css
    odd.hovered {
         background-color:red;
    }
    
    .even.hovered{
     background-color:red;
    }
    
    .highlight{
        background-color:yellow;
    }
    
    .odd{
    background-color:grey;
    }
    
    .even{
    background-color:#D3D3D3;
    
    }
```

```html
<!-- saved from url=(0061)https://csunix.mohawkcollege.ca/tooltime/10065/f15/zebra.html -->
    <html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"></head><body>
    <h2>2: Zebra Striping Demo</h2>
    
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
  
    
    <table width="200" border="1">
      <caption><a href="https://csunix.mohawkcollege.ca/tooltime/10065/f15/zebra.html#">UP</a> Zebra Striping Demo <a href="https://csunix.mohawkcollege.ca/tooltime/10065/f15/zebra.html#">DN</a></caption>
      <tbody><tr class="odd">
      <td>January</td> 
      <td>February</td>
      <td>March</td>
      </tr>
      
      <tr class="even">
      <td>April</td>
      <td>May</td>
      <td>June</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="highlight" >
      <td>July</td>
      <td>August</td>
      <td>September</td>
      </tr>
      
      <tr class="even">
      <td>October</td>
      <td>November</td>
      <td>December</td>
      </tr>
      
      <tr class="odd">
      <td>Monday</td>
      <td>Tuesday</td>
      <td> Wednesday</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="even">
    <td>Thursday</td>
    <td>Friday</td>
    <td>Saturday</td>
    </tr>
      <tr class="odd">
      <td>Spring</td>
      <td>Summer</td>
      <td>Fall</td></tr>
    </tbody></table>
    </body></html>
```

Comment: did you try anything to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```js
$(function() {
  $('#up').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $current = $('tr.highlight'),
      $previous = $current.prev();
    // remove current row's highlight
    $current.removeClass('highlight');
    // highlight previous row if it exist
    if ($previous.length)
      $previous.addClass('highlight');
    // otherwise highlight last row
    else
      $current.siblings().last().addClass('highlight');
  });

  $('#down').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $current = $('tr.highlight'),
      $next = $current.next();
    // remove current row's highlight
    $current.removeClass('highlight');
    // highlight next row if it exist
    if ($next.length)
      $next.addClass('highlight');
    // otherwise highlight last row
    else
      $current.siblings().first().addClass('highlight');
  });
});
```

```css
tr.odd {
  background-color: grey;
}
tr.even {
  background-color: #D3D3D3;
}
tr.highlight {
  background-color: yellow;
}
tr:hover {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table width="200" border="1">
  <caption><a href="https://csunix.mohawkcollege.ca/tooltime/10065/f15/zebra.html#" id="up">UP</a> Zebra Striping Demo <a href="https://csunix.mohawkcollege.ca/tooltime/10065/f15/zebra.html#" id="down">DN</a>
  </caption>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="odd">
      <td>January</td>
      <td>February</td>
      <td>March</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="even">
      <td>April</td>
      <td>May</td>
      <td>June</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="highlight">
      <td>July</td>
      <td>August</td>
      <td>September</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="even">
      <td>October</td>
      <td>November</td>
      <td>December</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="odd">
      <td>Monday</td>
      <td>Tuesday</td>
      <td>Wednesday</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="even">
      <td>Thursday</td>
      <td>Friday</td>
      <td>Saturday</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="odd">
      <td>Spring</td>
      <td>Summer</td>
      <td>Fall</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

By the way, you don't need to add a class to each row. You could use the [:nth-type selector](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_nth-of-type_odd_even) in your CSS to create alternative styles.